# PHP may be executing as a "privileged" group and user, which could be a serious security vulnerability

Tags: server, apache2, php

I ran some security tests on a Ubuntu 12.04 Server, and I've got these warnings :

```
PHP may be executing as a "privileged" group, which could be a serious security vulnerability.
PHP may be executing as a "privileged" user, which could be a serious security vulnerability.
```

In `/etc/apache2/envvars`, I have this:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

And all files in `/var/www` are having these user/group: `www-data:www-data`

Am I setting this correctly? What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The privileged user in this case is www-data. You see, PHP will run always with the www-data:www-data permissions, which can be detrimental if the environment is shared between many users / projects, since PHP can overwrite or modify any file that belongs to www-data, irrespective of the user who created the script.

Of course, this is not a problem if you are the only user creating PHP scripts on your machine, is it.

Also, the UID / GID of www-data might be below 100; since some policies grant special privileges to users with low UIDs, that may be a reason your software is complaining.

If you are worried, [read this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-security-best-practices-tutorial.html).